# Android. Скролл ListView c показом первой буквы итемов

Tags: java, android, listview

При скролле ListView необходимо, чтобы справа появлялась буква, как в "Контактах Android". На сколько мне известно - эта функция системная, но никак не получается реализовать. Помогите, пожалуйста.[image: Контакты Android]

Comment: Попробуй https://github.com/danoz73/RecyclerViewFastScroller или https://github.com/andraskindler/quickscroll

Comment: Эта функция не системная - класс ListView не реализует такой функционал и разработчик должен сам позаботиться о реализации или использовать готовую сторонюю библиотеку.